# SQL Query doesn't work within paypal IPN Listener page

Tags: mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

Ok, so i have some code I've written that inserts data into one of my tables, I've tested it a few times and it works fine, here is an example of the working code:

```
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usr", "pw", "db");

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5`, `column6`) VALUES ('e.g.', 'e.g.', 'e.g.', 'e.g.', 'e.g.', 'e.g.')";
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
```

this works fine and inserts the values into my table, BUT if i take this same code and try to use it within my PayPal IPN listener page it doesn't insert the values into my table...... I have verified my IPN listener works, so the problem seems to be in how I'm connected / inserted the values into my table?